# What is the difference between importing in <style> and <script> vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to vuejs, html and css. When I tried to import scss file in App.vue, it work if I import like this

```
<script>
    import '@/assets/scss/main-pc.scss')
</script>
```

However, if I imported it in `style`

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '@/assets/scss/main-pc.scss';
</style>
```

It didn't work properly and I encountered this error

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ../img/bg_login.png in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader
/dist/cjs.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
```

It seems the path to the image can't be loaded.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please check this `main-pc.scss` file. The error is saying that it cannot find this `bg_login.png` image relative to the component path where you are importing it.

Comment: @YomS. edited, it's actually one file.

Comment: No I meant, the file `main-pc.scss` itself, there has to be somewhere in this file where you are referencing this image file called "bg_login.png", have a look at [this post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328).

Comment: @YomS. Yes there is. But it worked fine when I import in script tag. I inspected, the problem might be caused after compiled, the css point to a different file name (/static/img/bg_login.99bd357.png) while it still point to `../img/bg_login.png` if imported in <style>

Comment: The `Style` is not meant for imports it is meant to contain local styles per compoennt (you can put the scoped option on it), importing should be done in the script.

Comment: What do you mean, @Michael? I would say it is totally valid to use import inside a components style tag. This is a common practice. However, mainly used for app-global styles/variables. Otherwise, I agree. Make your component as standalone as possible.

Comment: Have you resolved the `@` alias to point to your root in your webpack config?

Comment: @SølveTornøe Yes, I did

Answer (score 0):

The `import '@/assets/scss/main-pc.scss')` scss files shouldn't be inside the `<script>` as it is scss file. 
The scss files needs the respective loaders to compile and parse your css/scss/sass files.

Comment: what if we use sass-loader? is it able to import scss in `<style>`?

Comment: yes it does, as @michael mentioned, it is a good practise to contain the styles specific to that comp. if you want to add a reusable classes, better to add those in a global stylesheet, in your case a style.scss